# DataGridViewCheckBox does not get checked programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a table of Softwares, a table of Systems, and a table of InstalledSoftwares (ID, SysID, SoftID). I want to load all softwares to a DataGridView, and my DataGridView has 3 columns (ID,SoftName,installed), ID and SoftName are loaded from Softwares, installed is a chekbox that I want to be checked when a record exists in the InstalledSoftwares table for the Software. The installed column is not bound and its TrueValue is set to 1, and i fill it in a ForEach block like:

```
DGVIS.DataSource = Reports.installedSoftwares.Softwares();
IQueryable<InstalledSoftware> Installed = Reports.installedSoftwares.InstalledOn(SystemID);
        foreach (var ins in Installed)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGVIS.Rows)
            {
                if ((int)row.Cells["IDo"].Value == ins.SoftID)
                {
                    row.Cells["installed"].Value = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

but all of the checkBoxes are unchecked when I run the application, when I trace it the installed row gets the value 1 but when the foreach finishes every checkbox is unchecked and have the value of 0 (FalseValue is set to 0).

how can I make it work?

Comment: I've tried to replicate a code that is similar to above but I can't reproduce the same problem as yours.

Are you sure that you're not touching the cell's value anywhere else in your code?

Comment: @l46kok yes my friend I am sure I have not touched it anywhere else

Comment: When you are debugging the application, are you getting the value 0 on all cells after you exit the inner loop or the outer loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ignore my comments, I just noticed this line:

```
DGVIS.DataSource = Reports.installedSoftwares.Softwares();
```

You need to modify the datasource itself in order to reflect the changes made.

Answer (score 0):

Set the cell with true value:

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGVIS.Rows)
        {
            if ((int)row.Cells["IDo"].Value == ins.SoftID)
            {
                row.Cells["installed"].Value = true;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: i had tested this before asking question @Mitja Bonca, it didn't work